# Django can't find static folder

Tags: python, django

I am looking to add a css file to Django but it can't find the static folder.

Here is my settings.py file:

```
"""
Django settings for opengarden project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '__________'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'opengarden.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'wx', 'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'opengarden.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Denver'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = ''
```

My base html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% block title %}<title>Garden Dash</title>{% endblock %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    {% load static %}
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'wx/css/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>Plants</li>
            <li>Weather</li>
            <li>Soil</li>
            <li>Yield</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My folder structure is as follows:

gardendash > wx > static > wx > css > styles.css

and my style sheet is simply,

```
html {
    background-color: black;
}
```

I searched through stack overflow and found a couple solutions but they didn't fix the issue. I also found one that said to type the following to find my static location

> python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 css/style.css

the result I am receiving is

> No matching file found for 'css/style.css'.
>
> Looking in the following locations:
>   /home/my_name/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? I have tried adjusting the root url in settings.py to the folder directory as well but no luck.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS)

Comment: Change your static root from `/static/` to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` (Note - this is only true because your debug=True, when you use it for production, make sure you make necessary changes)

Comment: @BidhanMajhi still giving me the following in terminal ""GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1666"

Comment: @HåkenLid I have tried that from the document yet it still gives me the following in terminal ""GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1666"  and the stylesheet doesn't load.

Comment: @BidhanMajhi yes I added the following "urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)"

Comment: Check two things, first is there a `{% load static %}` (not staticfiles) tag? Second, make sure your static root is pointing towards the correct folder as per your project structure, it can be `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` or `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/appname')`

Comment: @BidhanMajhi thank you so much for the time but still no luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mention that the structure of your project is like this:

```
project_folder > app > static > app_name > css > styles.css
```

Since `styles.css` is inside your app's static directory, you can't simply access this file as `/static/css/styles.css`. This is the wrong path.

**The correct path is this: `/static/app_name/css/styles.css`**.

So, in your template you'd access your file like this:

```
{% static 'app_name/css/styles.css' %}
```

Also, make sure the app is listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

---

Additionally, let me clarify a few things:

1. `STATIC_ROOT`: This is the name of the directory where django will keep all the static files **when** you run `manage.py collectstatic` command. This is only required in production, otherwise this directory will and should be empty. The `collectstatic` command copies all static files from your apps and from your project.
2. `STATIC_URL`: This is the url prefix that django uses to **generate url paths** for static files. If `STATIC_URL` is set to `/static/`, django will convert `{% static 'file.jpg' %}` to `/static/file.jpg`.
3. `STATICFILES_DIRS`: This is a list containing paths to directories where you've kept your project specific static files. This is only required for development. When you run `collectstatic` command, Django will copy files from all the listed paths in this list and place them in the `STATIC_ROOT`.
4. You don't need to configure any url to serve static files because django does that by default during development as long as `django.contrib.staticfiles` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: So I changed the path and set STATIC_ROOT to be empty but still getting ""GET /static/wx/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1675" and the stylesheet is not loading. I updated my code in the post with your recommendations.

Comment: @DMellon Your app also needs to be in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list. Django only looks for static files in the listed apps.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved a similar issue by following steps:

1. Add the following line of codes inside `settings.py`

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

2. Then create a folder named static_root inside my project folder, and insert there my custom stylesheet or scripts.
3. Run the following command in my console:

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

I am using python3 on Ubuntu, If you are a windows user the command will be `python manage.py collectstatic`

Then all the static files that I saved inside static_root folder, and other necessary static files from the project, all files will be automatically generated inside the static folder.

4. Now inside my base `HTML` file add `{% load static %}`:

**Here is the Example:**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- custom css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">

    <title>Django Project</title>
</head>
```